# Passing parameters from textboxes to sql statement string - single quotes (') killing me

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, syntax

After adding text to cpr_txtbx, name_txtbx and address_txtbx I convert them to parameters to be used in my statement string.
The MySQL server I'm using wants the syntax: 
"INSERT INTO people (type, cpr, name, address)" VALUES('cpr', 'name', 'address')" (yup, single quotes) and I'm ripping out my hair trying to figure out the syntax here.

My button right now looks like this (I know it's wrong):

```
        private void add_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string statement = "INSERT INTO people (type, cpr, name, address)" +
            "VALUES('citizen', ':cpr', ':name', ':address')";
        this.AUD(statement, 0);
        add_btn.IsEnabled = false;
        edit_btn.IsEnabled = true;
        delete_btn.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

and AUD is:

```
        private void AUD(string statement, int state)
    {
        string msg = "";
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = statement;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                msg = "Borger tilføjet.";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("cpr", MySqlDbType.Text, 10).Value = cpr_txtbx.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("name", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = name_txtbx.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("address", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = address_txtbx.Text;
                break;
            case 1:
                msg = "Borger modificeret.";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("address", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = address_txtbx.Text;
                break;
            case 2:
                msg = "Borger slettet.";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("cpr", MySqlDbType.Text, 10).Value = cpr_txtbx.Text;
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if ( n > 0 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
                this.updateDataGrid();
            }
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and the tutorial I'm following is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiGsgctfiYM

This is the ONLY thing I can't get to work, so any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put parameter placeholders inside SQL string delimiters.

**Wrong:**

```
string statement = "INSERT INTO people (type, cpr, name, address)" +
        "VALUES('citizen', ':cpr', ':name', ':address')";
```

**Right:**

```
string statement = "INSERT INTO people (type, cpr, name, address)" +
        "VALUES('citizen', :cpr, :name, :address)";
```

---

Re your comment:

I took another look at the video tutorial you're using, and I see it's showing Oracle syntax. Keep in mind that every SQL database brand has its own syntax, in spite of using the standard SQL language. So you should use documentation and tutorials for the brand you use.

I'm not a C# developer, so I didn't notice at first that the syntax for query parameters in MySQL is different from Oracle.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html shows an example that has `@` as the sigil for parameters instead of `:`. So I assume you could fix your code by using this syntax:

```
string statement = "INSERT INTO people (type, cpr, name, address)" +
        "VALUES('citizen', @cpr, @name, @address)";
```

Then later add the values:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpr", cpr_txtbx.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name_txtbx.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address_txtbx.Text);
```

Comment: That's giving me an exception (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax;.......

Comment: @Bill Thanks - that's what did it! I was able to convert everything else but adding the @ did the trick. :)